# Help computing two regions for multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $0<a<b$ and let $D= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: a\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq b \}.$ I have to proof that $D$ can be expressed as the union of two elementary regions $D_1$ and $D_2$. I sketched $D$ and first I noted that $D$ is the region between two complete circles. One of those with radius $a$ and the other one with radius $b$. First I conjeture the following set $D_1$:

$D_1=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{b^2-x^2} \}. $

But the choose of $D_1$ mentioned above does not represent $\textbf{all}$ the positive half of the region $D$.

Was I clear in my description?

I need help computing $D_1, D_2$.

Note: I'm assuming that you know the definition of $\textit{elementary region}$, but if you don't, let me know and I'm going to put it there.

Thanks.

I'm a beginner.